# In how many ways can 4 red balls and 7 blue balls be arranged in 3 boxes

Tags: permutations

> In how many ways can 4 red balls and 7 blue balls be arranged in 3
>   boxes where each box must contain at least 1 red ball and each box can
>   contain less than or equal or 4 balls, under the following cases?
>
> (1) Each ball is distinct and Each box is distinct
>
> (2) Each ball is distinct and Each box is identical

My Attempt goes on like this

```
the only arrangement possible is
One box must contain 3 balls
and each of the remaining 2 boxes contain 4 balls
```

Options are

```
box          box        box
 1 red       1 red      2 red
 2 blue      3 blue     2 blue
```

OR

```
box          box        box
 2 red       1 red      1 red
 1 blue      3 blue     3 blue
```

Beyond this, I am not able to progress.

Can someone guide me how to approach these problems when  (1) Each ball is distinct and Each box is distinct and  (2) Each ball is distinct and Each box is identical.

Comment: If each ball is distinct, then the colors add nothing to the question.

Comment: Does someone know what "less than or equal or 4" mean? What is equal to what here? Was the intent to say "less than or equal to 4" which is the same as "no more than 4"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, 1 box must contain 2 red balls.  This box can contain 1,or 2 blue balls.  If it contains 1 blue ball then each of the remaining boxes must contain 3 blue balls each.  If it contains 2 blue balls, then one of the remaining boxes contains 2 blue balls and the final contains 3.

There are two cases: $(r^2b)(rb^3)(rb^3)$ or $(r^2b^2)(rb^2)(rb^3)$

> (1) Each ball is distinct and Each box is distinct

We must count the ways to choose boxes and balls to go in to them. For the first case: $3$ choices of one box, $^4C_2$ choices of red balls for it, $^7C_1$ choices of blue, then by symmetry it doesn't matter which of the other box we next choose (we don't want to over count) and there are $^2C_1$ and $^6C_3$ ways to select red and blue balls to put into it; the remaining balls go in the last box.  Thus the first case's count is: $3{^4C_2}{^7C_1}{^2C_1}{^6C_3}$

Can you count ways to select boxes and their balls in the second case? (Hint: not symmetric).

> (2) Each ball is distinct and Each box is identical

Here we just count ways to select the balls.

Comment: read your answer many times and practised with small examples to understand how the symmetry affect counting.

Comment: Can you count ways to select boxes and their balls in the second case? it would be 3*4C2*7C2*2*2C1*5C2 , am i correct?

Comment: Yes.  You are. @Kirian

Comment: Thanks  @Graham Kemp, so the total will be 3*4C2*7C1*2C1*6C3 + 3*4C2*7C2*2*2C1*5C2 which is 25200.  Elizabeth's answer 18720 is wrong. Please confirm. Now I will try to understand your answer for the second part (Each ball is distinct and Each box is identical) and post it here

Comment: can you also give more hint on how to count when Each ball is distinct and Each box is identical

Comment: Hint: you don't have to choose boxes.

Comment: got it. :) thanks. So, when each ball is distinct and each box is identical, answer is 4C2*7C1*2C1*6C3 + 4C2*7C2*2C1*5C2 = 9240, am I correct?

Comment: Your calculations are off. $\frac{4!}{2!}\frac{7!}{3!3!}+\frac{4!}{2!}\frac{7!}{2!2!3!} = 4200$

Comment: Kem, my mistake. thanks for the good explanation and guidance. I am able to solve similar questions now.

Comment: @GrahamKemp If all balls of same color are identical and if box is distinct then we would have 12 ways (6+6)right ?  And if boxes are identical then only 2 ways ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp:  For unlabeled teams for the $(r^2b)(rb^3)(rb^3)$ part, divsion by $2$ would seem needed because of two identical parts, i.e.  $^4C_2*^7C_1*^2C_1*^6C_3/2$

Comment: @GrahamKemp look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801451/distributing-balls-into-bins-with-some-conditions/4801463?noredirect=1#comment10213028_4801463

Answer (score 3):

Since balls are not identical we can label them as R1, R2, R3, R4, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, and B7.

Case 1: Boxes are identical

Let's first arrange the red balls into the boxes. Since there are 4 red balls and each box must contain at least one red ball, we must have a box with 2 red balls and 2 boxes with one red ball. The number of possible ways to do this is $\frac{4!}{2!} = 12$, because what we are doing is equivalent to choosing 2 red balls among {R1, R2, R3, R4}  and putting them into the same box and the other two red balls will be put into the remaining boxes, one for each.

When arranging the blue balls there are basically two possibilities: i) either we will have 4 balls in the box that is containing 2 red balls, or ii) there are 3 balls in the box that is containing 2 red balls.

For i) there are $ 42 \frac{5!}{3! 2!} = 420 $ possible ways to do this. Because we can choose two blue balls to put into the box that is containing 2 red balls in 42 ways and the remaining 5 blue balls will be grouped into 3 blue balls and 2 blue balls.

For ii) there are $7 \frac{6!}{3! 3!} = 140$ possible ways to do this. Because we can choose the blue ball to put into the box that is containing 2 red balls in 7 different ways and the remaining 6 blue balls will be grouped into two groups of 3 blue balls.

Therefore, the total number of possible ways is 12x(140+120)=3120.

Case 2:Boxes are not identical.

We will group the balls in the same way we described above and there are 3 groups of balls in each time. Then we can put these groups of balls into Box1 Box2 and Box3 in 6 different ways hence the correct answer is 3120x6= 18720.

Comment: I am clear with explanation given by @Graham Kemp . Trying to understand how your approach got different because this explanation also looks convincing. Can anyone help what has gone wrong here?