# There are 11 members in a family out of which there are 4 males and remaining females

Tags: permutations

> There are 11 members in a family out of which there are 4 males and
>   remaining females. The family has hired three cars for a trip to zoo.
>   The members are to be seated in the cars in such a way that there are
>   not more than four members in one car and there is at least one male
>   in each car. How many different ways can the members travel?
>
> Answer is given as 
>   4c1× 7c2+ 4c2×7c1+ 4c1×7c3+ 4c2×7c2 + 4c2×7c2+ 4c1×7c3
>   = 658
>
> source: question 2, [http://sakshieducation.com](http://sakshieducation.com/Bhavita/vidya/October/271014/Page1.pdf)

This is a question similar to this [site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1659517/in-how-many-ways-can-4-red-balls-and-7-blue-balls-be-arranged-in-3-boxes/1659546?noredirect=1#comment3385059_1659546), which I asked some time before and I got a good explanation from @Graham Kemp. This new question was found when I was searching for similar questions.

Answer can be

> 3*4C2*7C1*2C1*6C3 + 3*4C2*7C2*2*2C1*5C2 (if cars are distinct)

or

> 4C2*7C1*2C1*6C3 + 4C2*7C2*2C1*5C2 (if cars are identical).

So, the approach and answer given in the site referred (658) is wrong. Am I right?

Comment: Are the cars distinguishable?

Comment: @barak manos, it is not clear from the question. I solved in both ways as explained in my approach. But 258 does not come in both cases. But doubtful whether I am right or not.

Comment: Is the link broken?

Comment: @user36790, sorry it was broken. corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the site is counting the number of ways to pick people to fill the first cab to arrive when it has been decided that taxi I will take 3 passengers and both the others 4 each.

This does not count the number of ways to fill all three cabs.